# calculating convolution of (2t + 1) and y'(t)

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, convolution

Assume i have a function $y(t)$ that is differentiable twice such that there exists
$y'(t)$ and $y''(t)$

Im having a hard time calculating the convolution of $2t+1$ and $y'(t)$

What i did so far was write
$$
(2t+1)\star y'(t) = \intop_0^t[2(t-\tau)+1]y(\tau)d\tau = \intop_0^t2ty'(\tau)d\tau-2\intop_0^t\tau y'(\tau)d\tau + \intop_0^ty'(\tau)d\tau
$$

and got this so far
$$
\intop_0^t[2(t-\tau)+1]y(\tau)d\tau = 2ty(\tau)\bigg|_0^t+y(\tau)\bigg|_0^t-2\intop_0^t\tau y'(\tau)d\tau
$$

and im stuck at the last integral
$$
\intop_0^t\tau y'(\tau)d\tau
$$

Is there another way to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: The convolution integral need not even be finite, as there are no assumptions on $y'$.

Comment: there exists a y and y''

Comment: I edited the question, thanks for the comment

Comment: Do we have some information on what the function is? Like is it integrable or like the convolution of t and y(t) is given?

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting? A natural idea would be continuing to do integration by parts to your last integral; but from the very beginning, I would consider moving the derivative to $(2t+1)$ using the fact that $f' * g = f * g'$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This convolution was part of a bigger question where i had an ODE with convolutions to solve that was of the kind
$$
sint\star y'' + (2t+1)\star y' + sint y = 0
$$

The 2nd convolution is the one i got stuck at and how i eventually solved it was by leaving the integral and differentiating both sides of the equation so that i could use the fundumental theorem of calculus to get rid of the anoying integral like so:

$$
1)\ \ sint\star y'' = \intop_0^tsin(t-\tau)y''(\tau)d\tau = y'(\tau)sin(t-\tau)\bigg|_0^t+\intop y'(\tau)cos(t-\tau)d\tau \\
2) \ \ sint\star y = \intop_0^tsin(t-\tau)y(\tau)d\tau = y(\tau)cos(t-\tau)\bigg|_0^t - \intop_0^ty'(\tau)cos(t-\tau)d\tau
$$

So we get
$$
sint\star y'' + sint\star y = -sin(t)y'(0) + y(t)-y(0)cos(t)
$$

Then we go and solve the middle part of the equation (that i was having a problem solving)

$$
(2t+1)\star y' = \intop_0^t[2(t-\tau)+1]y'(\tau)d\tau = \intop_0^t2ty'(\tau)d\tau + \intop_0^ty'(\tau)d\tau - 2\intop_0^t\tau y'(\tau)d\tau \\
=2ty(\tau)\big|_0^t + y(\tau)\big|_0^t - \intop_0^t\tau y'(\tau)d\tau
$$

We can plug in and differentiate both side to get a first order linear ODE

$$
-sin(t)y'(0) + y(t)-y(0)cos(t) + 2ty(t)-2ty(0) + y(t) - y(0) = \intop_0^t\tau y'(\tau)d\tau
$$

After we differentiate we get the problem was the Right had side so i will only show how i handled it:

By the fundumental theorem of calculus:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\intop_0^t\tau y'(\tau)d\tau = ty'(t)
$$

Comment: Since there are no other answers, you might want to update the question and change the tag to solution verification. It appears that you would like to validate your approach inside this answer (which is different than your original question).